# Add lines to a document if they do not already exist within the document

Tags: bash

I am trying to say, if document does not exist, then create document. Next read each line of the document and if none of the lines match the `$site/$name` variables, then add the `$site/$name` variable into the document.

```
#!/bin/bash

site=http://example.com
doc=$HOME/myfile.txt 

if [ ! -f $doc ] 
then 
    touch $doc
fi 

read -p "name? " name 

while read lines
do 
    if [[ $lines != $site/$name ]]
    then 
        echo $site/$name >> $doc
    fi
done <$doc 

echo $doc
echo $site
echo $name
echo $site/$name
echo $lines
```

Typing test at the `read -p` prompt the results are

```
path/to/myfile.txt
http://example.com
test
http://example.com/test
```

I feel like I should know this but I'm just not seeing it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is initially empty, you'll never enter the loop, and thus never add the line. If the file is *not* empty, you'd add your line once for every non-matching line anyway. Try this: set a flag to indicate whether or not to add the line, then read through the file. If you ever find a matching line, clear the flag to prevent the line from being added *after* the loop.

```
do_it=true
while read lines
do 
    if [[ $lines = $site/$name ]]
    then 
        do_it=false
        break
    fi
done < "$doc"
if [[ $do_it = true ]]; then
    echo "$site/$name" >> "$doc"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The following creates the file if it doesn't exist.  It then checks to see if it contains `$site/$name`.  If it doesn't find it, it adds the string to the end of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
site=http://example.com
doc=$HOME/myfile.txt
read -p "name? " name
touch "$doc"
grep -q "$site/$name" "$doc" || echo "$site/$name" >>"$doc"
```

#### How it works

- `touch "$doc"`

  This creates the file if it doesn't exist.  If it does already exist, the only side-effect of running this command is that the file's timestamp is updated.
- `grep -q "$site/$name" || echo "$site/$name" >>"$doc"`

  The grep command sets its exit code to true if it finds the string.  If it doesn't find it, then the "or" clause (in shell, `||` means logical-or) is triggered and the `echo` command adds the string to the end of the file.

Comment: I think you meant to write `grep -q "$site/$name" "$doc" || echo "$site/$name" >>"$doc"` This works well too. Thank you.